# Проблемы переноса приложения WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, c++, clr

Я в отчаянии: на некоторых компах программа не запускается.

Дано: приложение WinForms, использующее dll на C++/CLR, .NET Framework 4.0, среда - Visual Studio 2012, разрядность х64.

Проблема: не запускается в Windows XP SP2 и в 32-битной Windows 7, то exception типа "не является win32", то exception типа "не удается загрузить dll или одну из ее зависимостей". Вроде тащу рядом все dll, но это не помогает. Стоит и VC++ redistributable, и .Net Framework соответствующей версии.

Задача: как-то запустить или правильно перекомпилить, чтобы всюду запускался. Ну или хотя бы создать несколько версий под разные условия. Но как?! Как это корректно перенести на .Net Framework 3.5? Какие нужно dll с собой тащить? В какой версии среды лучше?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте перекомпилировать приложение под 32-х разрядную архитектуру, скорее всего проблема именно в этом.